# MouseEvents don't fire on body when inner div has position fixed in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Look at [this example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44648654/stackoverflow/positionFixedTest/test.html)
Here is the code:
CSS:

```
div {
   position:fixed;
   top:100px;
   left: 320px;
   border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Javascript:

```
 var i = 1;
 $(document.body).mousemove(function () {
     $("#text").html(i++);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
      <span>Test Text: </span>
      <span id="text"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```

This code just updates the span while mouse is moved over the body. It works fine in Google chrome but in Firefox the span is only updated when mouse moves over the div, To debug I looked into firebug and found that the height of the body is 0, so the mouse is actually not moving over the body, but in Google chrome body covers whole document.

So My question is:

1. Which is the right behavior?(chrome's or firefox's)?
2. Is the right behavior documented somewhere?

Also surprisingly when I added this code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwd5m/), chrome started behaving like firefox, can someone explain me this unusual behavior also?

EDIT: I know I can make the code work in both browser by adding `height:100%` to body, I want to know why this different behavior in browsers and the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what's going on if you add this css:

```
body { border: 1px solid red; }
```

I'm not entirely sure of the reasoning, but Chrome decides that the 'body' element should be the full height of the window, whereas Firefox collapses the body element to a single line.  I believe the body collapsing is the correct behavior, because a 'block' element (such as `<body>` or `<div>`) should only be as tall as necessary to contain its contents (and since you made the inner div absolutely positioned, it won't take this into account in calculating its height).

The correct fix depends on your intended outcome, but you could use `document` or `window` instead of `document.body` because they represent the entire viewable window instead of just the actual `<body>` element.

You could also set your body to a specific height like 100%.  Alternatively, once you add more content to the body (stuff that isn't absolutely positioned), it will "fill out" and cause the mousemove event to fire properly anyway, so you won't need any of these fixes.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer,I know the fix,  I basically want to know about the behaviour and also  why does chrome behave like firefox when the code is added to fiddle? why does it change its behavior?

Comment: Well the behavior is caused, as I mentioned, because of Chrome's difference in how it handles the <body> element.  I believe Chrome is applying a non-standard effect to the body element to cause it to be full height.  The <body> element is a "block" element (which has a whole bunch of properties that I can't describe here, but one of those properties as that it should collapse to fit its contents).

I believe it doesn't have the same effect in jsFiddle simply because it is in an IFrame.  Chrome applies the full height effect to the main window, but not to IFrames.

Comment: It is not because of iframe, check this link https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44648654/stackoverflow/positionFixedTest/iframe.html

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Alex's answer I was still interested in the different behaviour. I found the solution: in jsfiddle you are not supposed to add the 'body' element in the html. If you remove that then you get the same behaviour as with the stand-alone page.

UPDATE:
That wasn't the case. The real reason is that the stand-alone page missed the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

declaration which caused a HTML version difference.

Comment: My mistake sorry. Then I still don't know the answer for that and it bugs me :(

Comment: Ok here it is: there is an additional line in jsfiddle, add this to the top of your document to get the same behaviour in the stand-alone page: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: thanks so it is basically html5 and html 4.01, thanks, update your ans, i will upvote it

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but I just realised that this one is also just a guess: I didn't see your non-jsfiddle page because dropbox access is disabled here. I hope at this time I am right.

Comment: Great to know there is a legitimate reason for the difference, other than Chrome just being weird :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/svineet/bwd5m/2/) works
Replaced `document.body` with `document` in 
`$(document.body).mousemove(function () {`

This also works on Firefox.

Comment: hey you removed `position:fixed` and also this is not what i wanted to know, I want to know the right behavior? please read my full question again

Comment: @Ankur, I have added position:fixed again

Comment: again please read my full question, I know i can easily add height 100% to body and it will work in both browsers, I want to know why this unusual behaviour

Comment: perhaps it is because document and document.body is the same in WebKit and represents the whole viewport.But in Gecko, document.body only includes the actual elements and document contains the whole viewport.Just a guess.

Comment: And i don't know whats happening with jsfiddle.

Comment: then why does chrome behave like firefox when the code is added to fiddle? why does it change its behavior?